# Disable or remove Shared Link for particular user in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

If a user leaves an organization, I need to remove their access from a site collection using Power Automate. I configured Power Automate to remove the user from the user information list. Even though their access has been removed, they can still view the shared link (people in organization can view) that was shared via email. Is there a way to remove/disable the shared link for the particular user because it is shared with many people?

Answer (score 0):

Select the file -> Manage access -> In the Links giving access section -> More options -> Remove link.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.